# GroupBy in EF Core 3.1 / EF Core 5.0 not working, even for the simplest example

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, ef-core-3.1, ef-core-5.0

I'm updating an EF6.x project to EF Core 3.1. Decided to go back to basics and follow the example of how to set up relationships from scratch again.

According to the official Microsoft documentation, [EF Core Relationship Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key), I translated the examples into a console app below:

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace BlogPostsExample
{
    class Program
    {
        async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // SQL Running in a Docker container - update as required
            var conString = "data source=localhost,14330;initial catalog=BlogsDb;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=<Your super secure SA password>;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;";

            var ctx = new MyContext(conString);

            await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

            var result = await ctx.Posts.GroupBy(p => p.Blog).ToArrayAsync();

        }
    }

    class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public MyContext(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = connectionString;
        }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder
                .UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
            }
        }
        public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Blog)
            .WithMany(b => b.Posts)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.BlogId) //Tried with and without these keys defined.
            .HasPrincipalKey(b => b.BlogId);
        }

    }
    public class Blog
    {
        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }

        public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }

    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public int BlogId { get; set; }
        public Blog Blog { get; set; }
    }
}
```

There is no data in the DB. EF Core fails to convert

```cs
ctx.Posts.GroupBy(p => p.Blog)
```

to a store query. This appears to me to be the simplest example of a GroupBy you could try.

When you run this code you get the following exception:

```cs
System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Post>
    .Join(
        outer: DbSet<Blog>, 
        inner: p => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(p, "BlogId"), 
        outerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(b, "BlogId"), 
        innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Post, Blog>(
            Outer = o, 
            Inner = i
        ))
    .GroupBy(
        source: p => p.Inner, 
        keySelector: p => p.Outer)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'
```

The only way to get this to work is to add something like AsEnumerable() before the `GroupBy`.

This is clearly not great from a performance point of view, it turns the group by operation into a client side operation where you really want to be doing grouping on the server side.

Have I missed something glaringly obvious? I struggle to believe that EF Core can't do the simplest group by that EF Framework has been doing since day 1. This seems like a fundamental requirement of any data driven app? (Or any app with a modicum of data!)

**Update:**
[image]

Adding a property, such as the Primary Key for the Blog in question makes no difference.

Update 2:

If you follow [this JetBrains article](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2020/11/25/getting-started-with-entity-framework-core-5/), you can do this:

```
var ctx = new EntertainmentDbContext(conString);
await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

var dataTask = ctx
                .Ratings
                .GroupBy(x => x.Source)
                .Select(x => new {Source = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .ToListAsync();

var data = await dataTask;
```

But **NOT** this:

```
var ctx = new EntertainmentDbContext(conString);
await ctx.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync();

var dataTask = ctx
                .Ratings
                .GroupBy(x => x.Source)
                // .Select(x => new {Source = x.Key, Count = x.Count()})
                // .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                .ToListAsync();

var data = await dataTask;
```

It only works with with an aggregating function, eg Count as above.

Something similar in SQL works

```
SELECT COUNT(R.Id), R.Source
FROM 
    [EntertainmentDb].[dbo].[Ratings] R
GROUP BY R.Source
```

But, removing the aggregating function, COUNT does not, you receive messages similar to:

`Column 'EntertainmentDb.dbo.Ratings.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

So it looks like I am trying to ask EF Core a question that I cannot ask in TSQL

Comment: Have you tried ctx.Posts.GroupBy(p => p.Blog.BlogId)? p.Blog "references" an entity (table in de DB), whereas p.Blog.BlogId references a property (column in the DB).

Comment: I did try that on my real application, and I just tried it on this super simple example, and you get System.InvalidOperationException: 'Client side GroupBy is not supported.'

Comment: During the life of my app I started with EF Framework mapping results of stored procedures to Entities as I could easily write the query in TSQL, but put the effort into converting it all to LINQ with EF, now I feel like I might have to go back to stored procedures - assuming that still works with EF Core!

Comment: As @Pepelui360 said, the id of the entity make more sense for a groupBy than the references of the objects coming from a dbContext.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#groupby for some explanation of why such `GroupBy` queries are not supported. SQL has no such query equivalent, hence the grouping has to be performed client side, and they want you to realize that and do it explicitly (with `AsEnumerable()` or similar). Here is the GitHub issue/discussion https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17068 if you want to join/vote.

Comment: @IvanStoev - TSQL and SQL Server do support GroupBy. As I said in my question this worked in 6.x with no issues translating this to a store query. This is an issue with EF Core. One thing I have never tried is using an aggregate inside the GroupBy in LINQ - I have never needed it, but could try I guess...

Comment: I tried this            var query = from p in ctx.Posts
                          group p by p.Blog.BlogId into g
                          select g.Key;

            var result1 = await query.ToArrayAsync();    this worked! The equivalent in Chained LINQ  await ctx.Posts.GroupBy(p => new { p.Blog.BlogId }).ToArrayAsync(); DOESNT work!?

Comment: I think the correct equivalent chained LINQ would be ctx.Posts.GroupBy(p => new { p.Blog.BlogId }).Select(g=>g.Key).ToArrayAsync(). Since version 3 in EF Core you must use the select method. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: @IanRobertson SQL `GROUP BY` supports `SELECT`-ing only key and aggregates. While LINQ `GroupBy` allows selecting keys and lists of correlated items. This ha no SQL equivalent and is the reasoning EF Core 3.0/3.1 designers are not willing to support it. EF6 is different framework, so what it supports and what doesn't is irrelevant. All we can do is to join the discussion/voting and somehow convince EF Core team to change their current decision.

Comment: I just tried running this sample with EF Core 5.0 as-is and get the same/similar exceptions

Comment: @IanRobertson the very logic of this query is wrong. SQL doesn't group by table names, it groups by specific fields. In SQL, the table isn't an entity, it's the *relation* between the values stored in the fields. `GroupBy(p => p.Blog) ` is meaningless. It's like trying to write `GROUP BY tbBlog` in SQL

Comment: @IanRobertson if EF 5 supported this - bad for the designers. That was a very, very, VERY bad idea, that used "magic" to pick the primary key for grouping, even if some *other* field would be more appropriate. What if only the blog title is included in the 
 final results? Wouldn't you want to group by `Title` in that case? Magic and opaque library decisions are bad

Comment: @IanRobertson besides, this `ctx.Posts.GroupBy(p => p.Blog).ToArrayAsync()` is meaningless in SQL. This groups nothing, it *has* to return all `Post` rows and shape them in two levels by `Blog`. I'm pretty sure this never worked in EF 5/6 either, as it requires client-side evaluation, something that never worked on EF by design.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos EF6 allowed a query like this. It just groups entities by another entity. EF6 actually did client-side grouping to implement this type of grouping. It just didn't allow client-side evaluation of user code.

Comment: @GertArnold I wonder why this unfortunate feature was added. On the one hand, EF wasn't supposed to use client-side evaluation at all. Except for this one case, which obviously made people think it did something it wasn't supposed to do. PS: I was in the MVP summit where they announced EF 1.0 and dev MVPs almost tore the dev team to pieces. Next year, it was the SQL MVPs that picked up the pitchforks and joined the devs.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Sure, EF has an "interesting" history. I guess there's no other option than client-side grouping if GroupBy is to be supported for other cases than only aggregates, because SQL can't return multi-level result sets.

Comment: @IanRobertson Is the final part of your question actually you answering the question? None of the C# code posted in this question aligns well with either grouping concepts in SQL or the actual posted SQL. This basically points to a misunderstanding of how GroupBy and GROUP BY work; they are considerably different. It is perhaps unfortunate that GroupBy is so named-PartitionBy might have been better, but ultimately it's just one of those things to learn: GROUP BY discards detail, GroupBy does not. There is no direct mapping unless GroupBy is followed by a particularly formed Select

Comment: @CaiusJard - I think my real issue is two fold - Where possible I'd like grouping to take place on the server rather than being evaluated client side which requires a lot more data to be transferred, then processed, and the other point is about adding AsEnumerable() to make client side evaluation actually work. The second part is a breaking change between EF6.x and EF Core. Perhaps its just making it more explicit. But also 3rdly - you can write valid LINQ that works against other sources, but does not work against SQL datastore... LINQ should work regardless of underlying store...

Comment: Understand the problem, but it seems like it arises from layers of abstraction not really being able to fully represent the layer below - and everything is this way; everything we have in any science is some approximation of what is below, and we have to remain aware of that. If you take something like file paths, `c:\temp` is fine on windows, but not on linux.. Swap it out for `Path.GetTempPath` so we can vary the behavior on linux/windows now that .NET exists on both, but what if .net is then ported to some platform that doesn't even have the concept of temp because no disk is writable?

Comment: Ultimately everything is imperfect and there may just be no good way of abstracting some high level concept up from what lies beneath. Maybe there is a bad way (and in the old days, it *was* a bad way - EF would just evaluate locally what couldn't be translated for remote) but the only sensible thing to do there is pass the decision off to the developer as to whether it should be made. As such, I don't think it's reasonable to say "LINQ should just work" any more than we could say "I should be able to get a temp path and write to it not matter what"; the abstraction breaking down is fatal

Comment: I do agree with you. But when is an IEnumerable/IQueryable not a true IEnumerable/IQueryable? .... when the underlying store is SQL Perhaps thats the problem, tying data classes to SQL that really shouldnt...

Answer (score 5):

Earlier EF/EF core automatically converted to client-side query evaluation when server-side evaluation was not possible.

Grouping by a key without select is not something supported by SQL and would always have been a client-side operation.

With EF 3.0+, they made it explicit on which query should run on server or on client. Technically it is better to explicitly know which query will run on server and what will run on client rather than a framework deciding it on our behalf.

You can read more about it here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client

Comment: By forcing the developer to add an .AsEnumerable() to force client side evaluation is not "explicit". "AsEnumerable" does not imply "client side". Ignoring this is querying SQL, from a pure LINQ perspective, this should be unnecessary.

Comment: LINQ is agnostic of data source but that results in not all linq feature being available at the source. By failing and forcing developer to add `AsEnumerable`, they are making them aware of source limitation. Without this, it could lead to people assume that it will happen at server side will their client is getting overwhelmed by data and impacting performance. I agree this topic is subjective. EFcore team chose a `fail fast` approach over the old `fail gracefully` approach. In my case, this feature has helped me transform my queries to get most of server-side compute while development.

Comment: It should be agnostic. It should work without `AsEnumerable` - using in-memory collections/lists/arrays, the LINQ would work fine. Only when you switch to SQL does it fail - so its not agnostic.

Answer (score -1):

Looks to me like the issue is that, as you say in your edits, that you're throwing some LINQ together that should work; but isn't being supported by the DB provider.

Unfortunately, the way EFCore seems to be working (I wasn't involved in creating it, so this purely based on observation); is instead of manipulating a queryable object on the server (which the LINQ you're using would work with), it's converting the LINQ to SQL and throwing it at the DB (from what I can tell). Until such a point as the team changes the EFCore functionality it looks to me like you've got two options:

Use LINQ or T-SQL to manipulate the data within the provisions of the database provider (i.e. using an aggregate specification).

Alternatively, create a local copy of the data within the .NET code by using the AsEnumerable or equivalent blocks and manipulate that. Whether you do this client-side or server-side is up to you (I'd advice doing it server side through an API call or something of that ilk.

Answer (score -2):

I think this may be an inappropriate use of GroupBy since you're not actually grouping by something new or aggregating data, instead use the existing relationship and select the Blogs and include posts.

*Note: Untested Code*

```
var blogs = ctx.Blogs.Include(x => x.Posts);
// Optional filters.
var blogsWithPosts = ctx.Blogs
    .Include(x => x.Posts)
    .Where(x => x.Posts.Any())  // Only blogs with posts
    .Where(x => x.Posts.Any(y => y.Title == "A Specific Title")) // Only blogs with posts that have the title "A Specific Title"
```

If you need to include only a subset of a blogs posts, you can do that too.

```
var blogsAndMathingPosts = ctx.Blogs
    .Where(x => x.Posts.Any(y => y.Title == "A Specific Title")) // Only blogs that have at least one post with "A Specific Title"
    .Select(x => new Blog() {
        BlogId = x.BlogId,
        Url = x.Url,
        Posts = ctx.Posts.Where(y => y.BlogId == x.BlogId && y.Title == "A Specific Title").ToList()
    );
```

Comment: I don't think that you quite understand the question/problem. If you ignore the fact that this relates to EF, and just think about this as LINQ queries, then what I tried should work no problem at all. The real problem comes from translation to a store query. EF is sort of breaking LINQ convention by tying it closer to T-SQL.

Answer (score -4):

Just do exactly what exception message says! You'll need to change 'var' to explicit as well.

I had this and had same exception message as you got:

```
var GroupByM2S =
            dbContext.CatL1s
           .GroupBy(x => x.UserId);
```

I changed to this. Tested and works fine.

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, CatL1>> MsGrpByAsEnumerExplicit =              
            (dbContext.CatL1s).AsEnumerable()
           .GroupBy(x => x.UserId);
```

So basically change 'var' as I have.
*The int here, IGrouping<int,...> is data type of your Grouping Key Prop/Col
Then surround dbContext.EntityName with pars and then .AsEnumerable().GroupBy(...)

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<dataTypeOfGpByKey, EntityName>> GrpByIEnumAsEnumExplicit =
        ( //<--Open Par dbCtx.EntityName
    .Join(
            outer: DbSet<Blog>,
            inner: p => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(p, "BlogId"),
            outerKeySelector: b => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(b, "BlogId"),
            innerKeySelector: (o, i) => new TransparentIdentifier<Post, Blog>(
                Outer = o,
                Inner = i
            )).AsEnumerable() //<-- Put here
                    .GroupBy(
                    source: p => p.Inner,
                    keySelector: p => p.Outer)
                    ...
```

Give that a shot for anyone with same exception message.

Comment: You can still use `var` here. The only difference is using `AsEnumerable()`, in other words: switching to client-side evaluation as the exception message suggests. But the question is more on the "why" of the change in `GroupBy` support and therefore, can't be answered.

Comment: It would not compile in my code using 'var'. Besides, why not be explicit when your know the type. I agree it is not the answer to more of the why, however it is a valid working answer to the exception message.

Comment: The problem I wanted to solve was to use LINQ and (very important "and") perform server side grouping. With/without the AsEnumberable, the LINQ on the face of it, should have the same behaviour. To me "AsEnumerable" doesn't imply - "lets do this grouping client side". For performance reasons developers would want to run grouping operations server side. But I would have liked to achieve it using expressive LINQ.

Comment: Of course you can use `var` in these isolated statements. As for "why not be explicit", you seem to have missed the reason for introducing the `var` keyword.