# Counting relations and getting distinct value

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a EF core question on how to build my query

```
class Report
{
    public Location Location { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Incident> Incidents { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset StartTime { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset EndTime { get; set; }
}

class Location
{
   public Guid Id { get; set }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

So, I have many reports, each report has a `Location`, `Incidents` and a time range of the report.

Now, I want to find distinct locations of reports in certain time range, and return the number of incidents on that locations.

| record-id | location-id | start-time | end-time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| r1 | loc1 | 2021-01-20 | 2021-01-22 |
| r2 | loc1 | 2021-01-24 | 2021-01-25 |
| r3 | loc2 | 2021-02-01 | 2021-02-02 |
| r4 | loc2 | 2021-02-02 | 2021-02-03 |
| r5 | loc1 | 2021-02-05 | 2021-02-07 |

| incident-id | report-id |
| --- | --- |
| i1 | r1 |
| i2 | r1 |
| i3 | r1 |
| i4 | r2 |
| i5 | r2 |
| i6 | r4 |
| i7 | r4 |
| i8 | r5 |

to find the distinct locations, i query

```
context.Reports
    .Where(r => r.StartTime >= startTime && r.EndTime <= endTime)
    .Select(r => r.Location)
    .Distinct();
```

At the end, i want a result set as where i get to locations (`loc1`, `loc2`) and incident count of 6 for `loc1` and incident count of 2 for `loc2`

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

### Idea:

Does this make sense?

```
var query = context.Reports
    .Where(r => r.StartTime >= startTime && r.EndTime <= endTime);

var resultSet = await query
   .Select(r => new
   {
       r.Location,
       IncidentsCount = query.Sum(x => x.Incidents.Count)
   })
   .Distinct()
   .ToArrayAsync();
```

### What I want

for a query from 2021-01-20 to 2021-01-25, i want one record with

```
[{
   Location = "loc1",
   IncidentsCount = 5  
}]
```

for the complete range (2021-01-20 to 2021-02-07) I want

```
[{
   Location = "loc1",
   IncidentsCount = 6  
},{
   Location = "loc2",
   IncidentsCount = 2  
}]
```

Comment: I can see a bug in your Report class definition. Add LocationId property.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a bug in your Report class definition. Add LocationId property:

```
public Guid LocationId{ get; set }
```

Try this query

```
var query = context.Reports
    .Where(r => r.StartTime >= startTime && r.EndTime <= endTime);
   .Select(r => new
   {
     LocationId=  r.Location.Id,
     IncidentsCount = r.Incidents.Count()
   })
     .GroupBy(o => new {o.LocationId})
                .Select(o => new 
                {
                    LocationId= o.Key.LocationId,
                    IncidentsCount = o.Sum(q => q.IncidentsCount) 
                }).ToArrayAsync();
```

or if you have a problem and not very many records
you can try this:

```
var query = context.Reports
    .Where(r => r.StartTime >= startTime && r.EndTime <= endTime);
   .Select(r => new
   {
     LocationId=  r.Location.Id,
     IncidentsCount = r.Incidents.Count()
   }).ToArrayAsync();

 var result=  query.GroupBy(o => new {o.LocationId})
                .Select(o => new 
                {
                    LocationId= o.Key.LocationId,
                    IncidentsCount = o.Sum(q => q.IncidentsCount)
                }).ToArray();
```

This will be certainly working but grouping will be on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but this would return an record per report found; i actually want to only one record per location to getter all incident counts of per location in the time range.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work:

```cs
var query = 
   from r in context.Reports
   from i in r.Incidents
   where r.StartTime >= startTime && r.EndTime <= endTime
   group i by new { r.Location } into g
   select new 
   {
      g.Key.Location,
      IncidentsCount = g.Count()
   };
```

Comment: i am running in similar problems as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59821484/groupby-in-ef-core-3-1-ef-core-5-0-not-working-even-for-the-simplest-example ... cant group-by Location (as it is a full object!?)

Comment: What is Location? Replace with LocationId or Location.Id, you have not shown all classes.